# What if the string in the Java split is not found

Tags: java, string, split

```
    String incomingNumbers[ ] = writtenNumber.split("\\-");
```

> The program accepts natural language numbers such as thirty-two or five.
>   So if five is entered, what lands in my incomingNumbers array?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: @donroby It splits it into thirty, two,  and five the way its supposed to. But when I try to use those to a access the keys in a hashmap, the exception I am using tells me it can't use them. I will use the comment box below to show you some of the code.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You get an array of size 1 holding the original value:

```
Input       Output
-----       ------
thirty-two  {"thirty", "two"}
five        {"five"}
```

You can see this in action in the following program:

```
class Test {
    static void checkResult (String input) {
        String [] arr = input.split ("\\-");
        System.out.println ("Input   : '" + input + "'");
        System.out.println ("    Size: " + arr.length);
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
            System.out.println ("    Val : '" + arr[i] + "'");
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        checkResult ("thirty-two");
        checkResult ("five");
    }
}
```

which outputs:

```
Input   : 'thirty-two'
    Size: 2
    Val : 'thirty'
    Val : 'two'

Input   : 'five'
    Size: 1
    Val : 'five'
```

Comment: private static HashMap numberMap = new HashMap();

    static
    {
        numberMap.put( new String ( "one" ), new Integer ( 1 ) );  etc             String incomingNumbers[ ] = number.split("\\-", 0);
        int multiplicand = 0;if ( numberMap.containsKey( incomingNumbers[ 0 ] ) )
        {
            multiplicand += (Integer)numberMap.get( incomingNumbers[ 0 ] );
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception();

        }

Comment: @don roby Actually the ones with the "-" like thirty-two work fine but not the single one like five or six or nineteen.

Comment: By the way, does anyone know why my question has a -4 assigned to it?

Comment: @ArmandoMoncada it seems you have wrote that you  have not tried. Next time use Eclipse and the debugger to look inside arrays

Comment: @cl-r but sometimes you don't want to try and have instant know-how